# Yii-1.1.12 framework, using another controller

Tags: php, yii

I try to make website with yii framwork, and make friendly urls. In 
If i use friendly urls like:

```
http://localhost/eshops/     -> calls protected/controllers/SiteController->actionIndex()
http://localhost/eshops/login -> calls protected/controllers/SiteController->actionLogin()
http://localhost/eshops/logout -> calls protected/controllers/SiteController->actionLogout()
 ...
```

But how to use another controller AbcController like

```
http://localhost/eshops/abc/a -> calls protected/controllers/AbcController->actionA()
http://localhost/eshops/abc/b -> calls protected/controllers/AbcController->actionB()
```

that it don't show "Error 404"?

.htaccess is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Rules are in protected/config/main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'gii'=>'gii',
        '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

Thank you

Comment: We need to see your .htaccess and your urlManager rules

Comment: Also show your urlManager rules

Comment: Do your baseUrl is http://localhost/eshops/ or http://localhost/ ?

Comment: Do the second set of URLs work when you remove the <action> rule?

Answer (score 1):

You need remember order of executing rules! You need just set right rule's order

```
'rules'=>array(
        'gii'=>'gii',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<action:(login|logout|register|contact)>' => 'site/<action>',
//      or full access 
//      '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
    ),
```